# Assign comment & comment out shortcut to the same key

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, dreamweaver

I want to add comment & comment out keyboard shortcut and assign it to the same keyboard shortcut, namely the popular <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>.

So far I was only capable of assigning only 1 shortcut to a key combination, due to *Dreamweaver* deleting the other one already set. How can I do it?

Comment: Are you asking how to add shortcuts to Dreamweaver?  What version are we talking about?

Comment: I know how to add one, I don't know how to add 2 to the same key combo. One for commenting, and if that line is already commented out- decomment it with the same key combo. Virtually every IDE I used so far had this integrated and I am sure DW has it too.I am using Dreamweaver CC 2015

Comment: So you want the the same shortcut to add and remove the desired comment character(s)?  I have used hundreds of IDEs over a 2 and half decade period and I have never used a single IDE where the shortcut to add a comment was the same as it was to remove a comment.'

Comment: Wow. That sucks. Never used eclipse or xcode? Anyways, do you have an idea how this could be accomplished?